# C# update imported data with \n

Tags: c#, forms, tcp, textbox

Please be advised that I am a beginner in C#.

I am writing a remote administrator tool that is sending CMD controls to the client and returning results to the server.

In this example, when I view the returned data in Debug.Console, it is in two rows as in the below image.

[image]

But what I see in the txtBox is all concatenated...

[image]

How do I split the text by rows in the txtBox as in the imported data?

This is how I populate the txtBox in the server side:

```
if (strdata.StartsWith("2"))
                    {
                        updateText(txtCmdConsole, strdata);
                    }


private void updateText(TextBox text, string strdata)
        {
            text.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                text.AppendText(strdata.Substring(2));
            });

        }
```

Here is the Cmd output handler:

```
private void CmdOutputDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
            StringBuilder strOutput = new StringBuilder();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
            {
                try
                {

                    strOutput.Append(outLine.Data);
                    Debug.WriteLine(strOutput);
                    buffer = encoder.GetBytes("2 " + outLine.Data+ "\n");
                    networkStream = newclient.GetStream();
                    networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    networkStream.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception err) { }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lines are separated by `\n` instead of `\r\n`, simply use a string replace:

```
strdata = strdata.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

Then the TextBox should display the lines correctly.

Note that e.g. on Unix/Linux the defualt line separator is `\n` (line feed, LF). On Windows it's `\r\n` (carriage return / line feed, CR/LF).

Comment: Thank you soo much..... i spent more than an hour trying to figure this out...